# Questions about data output in Python and Excel

Tags: python, for-loop, break

For **Excel** use, I want to create a code that represents A1, A2,...D1, ... AB1, AB2, ...

```
field = [A, B, C, ..., AA, AB, ..., YZ, ZZ]
data = [[1, 2,3,4,5], [2, 3,4,5,6], [3, 5,4,3,5], [4, 5,6,7,7],...] #[index, data1, data2,...]

for i in field:                # A, B, C, ...
    for j in range(0,10):      # First index in data
        for k in range(1,4):
            print(str(i)+data[j][k])
```

The result I want is
**A2 A3 A4 A5 B3 B4 B5 B6 C5 C4 C3 C5**
...

I think I need to use a break statement, but how do I do that?

Comment: The problem you are encountering is that you want to pair up each element of `field` with the corresponding sub-list from `data` first (before iterating over the sub-list to make your outputs). But these nested loops mean to use every element of `data`, for each element of `field` (i.e. for 10 fields and 10 data sublists, you get 100 results instead of 10). Solving this is called iterating *in parallel*. Please see the linked duplicate to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, column in enumerate(field):  # A, B, C, ...
    for j in range(len(data)):      # Iterate over rows in data
        if j < 10:  # Limit to first 10 rows if necessary
            for k in range(1, 5):   # Assuming you want to skip the first element in each row and limit to next 4
                if i < len(data[j]) - 1:  # Check if column exists in this row
                    print(f"{column}{j+2}: {data[j][k]}")
                else:
                    break  # Break if the column index exceeds the data row length
```

Comment: Thanks but above result is A2: 2
A2: 3
A2: 4
A2: 5
A3: 3
A3: 4
A3: 5
A3: 6
A4: 5
A4: 4
A4: 3
A4: 5
A5: 5
A5: 6
A5: 7
A5: 7
B2: 2
B2: 3
B2: 4
B2: 5
B3: 3
B3: 4
B3: 5
B3: 6
B4: 5
B4: 4
B4: 3
B4: 5
B5: 5
B5: 6
B5: 7
B5: 7
C2: 2
C2: 3
C2: 4
C2: 5
C3: 3
C3: 4
C3: 5
C3: 6
C4: 5
C4: 4
C4: 3
C4: 5
C5: 5
C5: 6
C5: 7
C5: 7
D2: 2
D2: 3
D2: 4
D2: 5
D3: 3
D3: 4
D3: 5
D3: 6
D4: 5
D4: 4
D4: 3
D4: 5
D5: 5
D5: 6
D5: 7
D5: 7

Comment: The result I want is A2 A3 A4 A5 B3 B4 B5 B6 C5 C4 C3 C5...

Comment: This is completely wrong as it fails to understand the problem OP encountered. (Said problem is also a common duplicate.)